# Java Exception sending email using smtp.office365.com

Tags: java, spring-boot, certificate, office365, jakarta-mail

Since yesterday, sending emails using JavaMailSender has failed using smp.office365.com as the smtp server. The certificate is correctly loaded into the keystore but the system logs this exception:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
... 99 common frames omitted
```

Does anyone have any idea what it could be. It worked for 2 months without any problems and the certificate is still valid

Comment: They must have changed their certificate.

Comment: @MandarPandit Edit rejected. You removed the actual exception. Don’t do that.